# Dapper and access returning blank values

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, dapper

I'm trying to pull data from an Access database using dapper. I have the following class defined to use the fields from the access database that I need to read. I then tried to pull the data using the code below. When I run this only blanks come back. The number of blanks match the number of records in the data table.

I tried to use a shorter sql string with the same results.

I can't find any information on this issue, does anyone have any ideas about this?

```
public class DLabResults
{
    public int ResultsFolderNumber { get; set; }
    public int Request { get; set; }
    public int Release { get; set; }
    public string Formulation { get; set; }
    public string Container { get; set; }
    public string Closure { get; set; }
    public string Shipper { get; set; }
    // public string Label_Back { get; set; }
    // public string Label_Front { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

public void LoadDapperDLabResults(List<DLabResults> items)
{
    string sql = "";
    //sql = "SELECT tblResults_Results.R_Project_Assignment, tblResults_Results.R_Project_Request, tblResults_Results.R_Project_Release, tblResults_Results.R_Formulation, tblResults_Results.R_Closure, tblResults_Results.R_Container, tblResults_Results.R_Shipper, '' AS Blank1, '' AS Blank2, tblResults_Results.R_Test_FullPath FROM tblResults_Results WHERE(((tblResults_Results.R_Formulation)Like '*' & [Formulation] & '*') AND ((tblResults_Results.R_Closure)Like '*' & [Closure] & '*') AND((tblResults_Results.R_Container)Like '*' & [Container] & '*') AND((tblResults_Results.R_Shipper)Like '*' & [Shipper] & '*')) ORDER BY tblResults_Results.R_Project_Assignment, tblResults_Results.R_Project_Request, tblResults_Results.R_Project_Release;";
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblResults_Results";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\DavidsoJ\\Desktop\\Fixed Push Workbooks\\Redesigned Databases\\Development Lab Results Database.accdb"))
    {
        //var TM2 = connection.Query<DLabResults>(sql).ToList();
        List<DLabResults> TM2 = connection.Query<DLabResults>(sql).ToList();
        //add items to employess    
        if (items == null || items.Count < 1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            TM2.AddRange(items);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = TM2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by blanks"? object with no properties populated or just a collection of null?

Comment: The column names from the long sql do not seem to match up with the properties of the desired object model.

Comment: By blanks I mean in the datagridview the data came back as 0 0 0 blank blank etc. where blank means there was nothing there. I will try changing the object model field names.

Comment: The properties of the object model appear to be the key, when I changed it to match the filed name exactly it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @jrdnoland The other option is to change the query to rename the columns like this `Select UglyTableName As NicePropertyName, ...`

Answer (score 3):

The column names from the SQL query do not seem to match up with the properties of the desired object model `DLabResults`.

Either update the columns names returned from the query to match the object

```
SELECT tblResults_Results.R_Project_Request AS Request
/*, ... code removed for brevity */
FROM tblResults_Results
```

OR update the `DLabResults` property names to match the column names returned from the query

```
public class DLabResults {

    public int R_Project_Request{ get; set; }

    //... code removed for brevity
}
```

Either way, when using dapper the column names need to be mapped to object members in order for dapper to populate them.